# Thymeleaf + Spring Secucity -> #authentication not working in link location combined with another

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use the notation `${#authentication.systemUser.tenant.url}` inside a link (`@{}`). This usage works to me when I try to do the same thing in text location (`${}`).

**My code:**

**Text location:**

```
<strong th:text="${#authentication.systemUser.name}" />
```

This is printing **Maciel Bombonato** in the screen.

**Link location:**

```
<a th:href="@{/${#authentication.systemUser.tenant.url}/user}" > 
    <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>
    <span th:text="#{user.dashboard}" />
</a>
```

This create a link to `http://localhost:8080/${#authentication.systemUser.tenant.url}/user`, but I'm waiting for `http://localhost:8080/apolo/user`.

After write this question I do one last test and work.

My solution is below.

First create one div to use th:with to create some variables and involve the links and in this th:with the link will be composed.

```
    <div th:with="dashboard=${'/'} + ${#authentication.systemUser.tenant.url} + ${'/user'},
          profile=${'/'} + ${#authentication.systemUser.tenant.url} + ${'/user/view/'} + ${#authentication.systemUser.id}
" >
        <a th:href="@{${dashboard}}" >
            <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>
            <span th:text="#{user.dashboard}" />
        </a>

    </div>
```

In this case, I declared all variables in the DIV and then use it in link.

And now the link generated was: `http://localhost:8080/apolo/user`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is related to building the href url with a value from a 
variable expression.

You could use the pipe `|` to perform the literal substitution ([doc](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions)).

```
<a th:href="@{|/${#authentication.systemUser.tenant.url}/user|}" > 
    <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>
    <span th:text="#{user.dashboard}" />
</a>
```